# Why the return value of fork() is not in the reverse way?

Tags: linux, operating-system

We know that the `fork()` creates a new child process and returns the child's PID to the parent and `0` to the child.What I was thinking that why they have designed it in this way (return value),why the return value is not in the reverse order.I think returning the parent's PID to child and `0` to the parent may also work,every child would know who is its parent and whenever it gets terminated it will signal to its respective parent process,what will the consequences of this approach? Am I missing something?

Comment: The parent needs to `wait` for the child, so it needs the child's PID. Not the other way round. The child can already get the parent's PID easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it's this way is that any child can get the pid of its parent by calling `getppid`, while the parent won't know what the child's pid is without `fork` telling it.

If the parent wants to wait for a specific child to exit, it needs to pass the child's pid to `waitpid`.

Comment: I think if would be in the reverse way then must have designed a function to get child's pid for parent.So I think this is not the real reason behind it.

Comment: @RajeevSingh A process can have multiple children but only one parent.  So `getppid` will always return the pid of the calling processes's parent.  Even if you could get the list of child pids, you'd need to know which is which.

Answer (score 0):

The child process can get the parent's PID by getppid(). Therefore the parent needs fork to get the PID of the child process

Answer (score 0):

If they designed like, fork() returns 0 to the parent process then in the case of one parent process is creating multiple child processes.

if multiple fork() creates a child process and all returns  0's to the same parent process. There is no way to identify the individual child processes and designed to return child process id to the parent.